# create like button using react native and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm beginner in react-native and I'm actually developing a event application in React-Native , i'm trying to create a like/dislike button . that's my code but not work

```
  const [likes,setLikes] = useState('');
const [liked,setLiked] = useState(false);


const eventInfo = ()=>{
    const getInfo = firebase.database().ref('/users/event/' +postKey)
    getInfo.on('value', snapshot => {
        console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val())
        setLikes(snapshot.val().likes)
       // setIntersted(snapshot.val().interested)
       // setInterestedNmb(snapshot.val().interestedNmb)
       // setInterestedName(snapshot.val().interestedName)
        setLiked(snapshot.val().liked)
      });
}

const like = () => {
    const updateLike = firebase.database().ref('/users/event/' +postKey)
    updateLike.update({
        likes: likes +1 ,
        liked: true
    })
  };

  const dislike = () => {
    const updateLike = firebase.database().ref('/users/event/' +postKey)
    updateLike.update({
        likes: likes -1 ,
        liked: false
    })
  };
```

the problem is when i press `<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> like() />`  by one user . like transform to true in all users . i want to create a list if a user press like . the user id added to the list . and if the user id is in the list like is true . if the user id isn't in the list . like is false 
give me a solve please
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe a little better what problem are you facing?

Comment: thank you for your comment , the problem is when i press   `<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> like() />  ` by one user  like transform to true in all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code what I understand is, you have initialised variable likes as string

```
const [likes,setLikes] = useState('');
```

if you make this function work on this variable

```
const like = () => {
const updateLike = firebase.database().ref('/users/event/' +postKey)
updateLike.update({
    likes: likes +1 ,
    liked: true
})};



 const dislike = () => {
const updateLike = firebase.database().ref('/users/event/' +postKey)
updateLike.update({
    likes: likes -1 ,
    liked: false
})};
```

then your addition will give you output like 111 if you clicked like button 3 times and dislike will give you 11 if clicked after.
So you need to initialise your variable as integer like this

```
 const [likes,setLikes] = useState(0);
```

If you are getting any other error feel free to comment.

Comment: thank you for your comment , the problem is when i press   `<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> like() />  ` by one user . like transform to true in all users . i want to create a list if a user press like . the user id added to the list . and if the user id is in the list like is true . if the user id isn't in the list . like is false .i hope you understand me and my bad english

Comment: you can achieve that via redux or mobx, by keeping count same throughout the app whenever any actions takes place like or dislike.

Comment: And after that store that value in firebase db and call it on componentdidmount.